# Dynamice tableview Cell with Addsubview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I need to add multiple checkbox in my tableview cell , so that cell size automatically increase as per number of checkbox buttons at runtime. How can I do it ?

My custom cell

[image]

```
import UIKit

class checkboxCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBoxView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

**My code for display cell with runtime adding checkbox with label**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

............
.................
if indbexpath.row == 4
        {
            var checkBoxcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"checkboxCell") as? checkboxCell
            if checkBoxcell == nil{
                let arrNib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("checkboxCell",owner: self, options: nil)!
                checkBoxcell = arrNib.first as? checkboxCell
            }
            checkBoxcell?.txtLabel.text = "Sample Checkbox"
            
            let checkBoxArray =  NSMutableArray(array:model.idnamemodelUI! as NSArray)
            
            for i in 0..<checkBoxArray.count {
                let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: i * 45, width: 30, height: 30))
                checkbox.checked = false
                checkbox.tag = "This is a label"
                 checkBoxcell?.contentView.addSubview(checkbox)
                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: i * 45, width: 200, height: 30))
                label.textAlignment = .left
                label.text = labelName
                checkBoxcell?.contentView.addSubview(label)                
                
            }
            
            return checkBoxcell!
            
        }

............
.......
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100 //66
    }
```

Desired output looking for

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1: Use a nested table, add another check box table inside the main table view cell and make the inner table dynamic (https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab).

Approach 2: Use the stack view. Add UIStackView in content view and give top, bottom, left, right constraint and bind the outlet with cell after that, use stack view property addArrangedSubview to add your chack box view into the stack view.

Approach 3 (Not recommended): In your code, you used a fixed size of check box view so, in heightForRowAt method calculate the height for cell and return calculated height. e.g. suppose check box count is 5 then the final height is (checkBoxCount * (fixedCheckBoxViewHeight + spaceBetweenTwoCheckBox))

Comment: can you explain Approach 2: Use the stack view. Add UIStackView in content view and give top, bottom, left, right constraint and bind the outlet with cell after that, use stack view property addArrangedSubview to add your chack box view into the stack view.

Comment: For the second approach first, add one verticle UIStackView in your cell XIB and bind the outlet of UIStackView. After in cell for you are creating check box view so just add that check box view inside the stack view.

Comment: will it display multiple checkbox on the same cell and expend cell size swell?

Comment: Yes, it will display multiple checkboxes on the same cell as per your code you have added row condition so. And it will expand cell size according to the content of the cell.

Comment: I tried same approach its not working,any sample will be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry not available at the moment.